# How would I make my Python program unpack a compressed file I drag over it?

Tags: python, windows, zip

I am trying to make a program which when I drag my .zip file over the program.py or when I compile it as a program.exe, in the Windows file browser I can drop it and the program unpacks the contents to a specific location that I can access. This then will have further programming but this is all I really need at this point. I am working with Python 3.4.2, 32bit, Windows 7.

Comment: anyhting you drag onto a program should be passed in as an argument to the program using standard `sys.argv` to access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the following code as `unzip.py` and then run it by typing `python unzip.py file_to_unzip_.zip C:\Destination` in cmd.

```
from sys import argv
from zipfile import ZipFile

def unzip(source=None, destination=None):
    zip = ZipFile(source)
    return zip.extractall(destination)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unzip(source=argv[1], destination=argv[2])
```